# Mongodb applying aggregate method based on condition

Tags: mongodb, express

If it is possible to use aggregate and add or remove limit based on condition. Currently this is the aggregate code that I have:

```
return this.aggregate([
  { $match: { chatRoomId } },
  { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
  // do a join on another table called users, and
  // get me a user whose _id = postedByUser
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "postedByUser",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "postedByUser",
    },
  },
  { $unwind: "$postedByUser" },
  // apply pagination
  { $skip: options.page * options.limit },
  { $limit: options.limit },
  { $sort: { createdAt: 1 } },
]);
```

I want to remove `$skip` and `$limit` if `options.limit` has value or not. I could do an if/else or switch statement to achieve this but I am just checking if there is a mongo way or express way to do this. Below is not a DRY approach though.

```
if (options.limit > 1) {
  // return this.aggregate([code with skip and limit]);
} else {
  // return this.aggregate([code without skip and limit]);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can attempt with this approach: 1. Create a (`pipeline`) array for stages (add `$match` until `$unwind` stages into it). 2. An if statement, if fulfilled for skip/limit, add `$skip` & `$limit` stage into the (`pipeline`) array. 3. Pass the array into `this.aggregate(pipeline)`  . Not sure is this meet your requirement or not.

Comment: Is what you said the same as @Tom's answer? I was gonna ask you to give an example code.

Comment: Yes, the concept is the answer code that @Tom's written. You add those stages when the condition met in the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Mongo-y way to execute a conditional pipeline stage.

Your current approach is the correct one, you can obviously play with the syntax a bit to make to make it cleaner, for example:

```
const paginationPipeline = [
    { $skip: options.page * options.limit },
    { $limit: options.limit },
];

return this.aggregate([
    // prev pipeline
    ...(options.limit ? paginationPipeline : []),
    { $sort: { createdAt: 1 } },
]);
```

Comment: is this the same what @Yong Shun said?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I will try to implement this .

Comment: Sorry for late reply. This worked. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution... conditionally add the steps to an array, then pass the array to the aggregation pipeline:

```
const stages = []

if (searchTerm) {
  { 
    text: {
      path: ['name', 'description'],
      query: searchTerm,
    }
  }
}

if (category) {
  stages.push({ text: {
    path: 'category',
    query: category,
  }})
}

const result = await Product.aggregate([
  {
    $search: {
      compound: {
        must: stages
      },
    }
  },
])
```